# How to change the ViewController within a TabBarController by selecting a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to transition to a different `UIViewController` (which is part of a `UITabBarController`) by selecting on a cell.

I have a `HistoryViewController` where this cell and tableview is contained. This History View Controller is "present modally current context" once a user logs in with through the `LoginViewController`. Not sure if this matters to the problem or not, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Here is the hierarchy:

-`LoginViewController`
   -> `HistoryViewController` (this is where the code listed below is)

-`ViewController` (where I am trying to go once a user clicks on a particular cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    LocationInformation.city = locations[indexPath.row].city
    LocationInformation.state = locations[indexPath.row].state

    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

The goal is to set the location's city and state to the global variables "LocationInformation" (which works) and then change to the `ViewController` which does not work.

The code `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1` works in a different viewController I have called "searchViewController", where the user enters their location and state.

Comment: Where does your tab bar controller appear in your hierarchy?

Comment: If your “History VC” is presented modally in “Login VC”, then it will not have tabBarController property. Looks like your “Login VC” is the root controller and it will have tabBarController pointer. You can make “Login VC” the delegate of “History VC” or maybe review your views hierarchy

Comment: @Callam the "ViewController" and "LoginViewController" (which leads to the "HistoryViewController" are both under the TabBarController. Like lobstah said the "Login VC" is the root controller.

Comment: @lobstah Yes the LoginViewController is the RootViewController, what is the best way going about making "Login VC" the delegate of "History VC"? Or is there a better way to present a login before a user can access the "HistoryViewController"?

Comment: So `HistoryViewController` and `ViewController` are child view controllers of the tab bar controller?

Comment: @Callam ViewController and LoginViewController are. HistoryViewController gets "present modal with current context" when a user logins through the LoginViewController.

Comment: I would prefer to create one move VC (lets call it Root) which will be responsible for showing Login or History, depending on actual state of your app. It can show modally Login before user login and then dismiss Login and present History. But still you need to pass data from Login and History to this Root VC so it will know what to do. You can choose any approach you like to achive it (delegation, completion handler, notifications, reactive programming, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

> This History View Controller is "present modally current context" once a user logs in with through the LoginViewController.

When you presented your controller modally then the new stack did not has tabBarController. You can check this by debugging the value of self.tabBarController, I think it will be `nil`

**Solution**

If TabBarController is the root View Controller, Use this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    LocationInformation.city = locations[indexPath.row].city
    LocationInformation.state = locations[indexPath.row].state

    let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController
    (rootViewController as? UITabBarController)?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```